# Interactivity on UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am newbie working on iOS application for iPad. I have successfully implemented a children's book app using UIImageView. I have also implemented swipe gestures to traverse across the pages. Each page is loaded as single image inside UIImageView and plays an audio narrating the scene.

Now I would like to add some interactivity to my pages. For example, I have a single image loaded in UIImageView which contains few animal characters and some dialect for that particular scene... I want whenever user tap on a particular animal, it should show some movement (may be as if lion is roaring) and my app should play a audio file containing that animal's sound... how can I achieve this functionality? I need to understand the concept so I can implement it. Should I be having separate images for all animals and load them in their own UIImageView and have all these UIImageViews inside main (or background) UIImageView? I would appreciate if someone can explain me the concept of how such functionality should be implemented.

I think for touches on animals I can define a list of CGRects that will act as hot-spots for each animal on the screen and then play sound files for touched animals but how can I define these hot-spots dynamically? because these would very on each page based on animal's position on a particular page/image. Also this might not help me with implementing some movement/animation for a particular animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An invisible button should work.  Use a 1 pixel transparent png, and then size the button dynamically to fit the area you want tapped:

```
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(7, 5, 73, 30);
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_pixel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

(you don't need to dealloc the button, because it was not alloc'ed in the first place)

Then, just create a function called "doSomething" that...does what you want.  In your example, it would play the animal sound.

Comment: Thx Jeffrey, I'll try this approach. It might sound silly but how can I find the coordinates of the animal position inside my image (with couple of animals sitting in a jungle) so I can create a frame for the button there?

Comment: If you open the image in Photoshop and move the mouse around (with the Info panel open) you can get the x and y coordinates.  Then draw a mask and look at the w and h values for width and height...  You can also "eyeball" it -- it doesn't have to be perfectly accurate.

Comment: When testing, I like to swap the btn_pixel.png file for one with a solid color (like bright green) so I can then see where the touch areas are.  :-)

Comment: Thx Jeffrey, that's very helpful and I should be able to handle it now. Appreciate your help and tips.

Answer (score 0):

If the animals have pictures that are separate you should use them as UIButtons and make their picture "custom" and select your animal-pictures.

Otherwise maybe put an invisible button on-top of the animals and then do the code below, I think an .png with transparency with the right size and a custom UIButton should work!

To make these buttons do sounds, do:

```
-(IBAction)lionRoar {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"LionRoar" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio play];


}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx Phill. Currently, animals are not separate pictures, I have ONE image showing couple of animals sitting in a jungle.

Comment: Maby an invisible button on-top of the animals with the code I showed above? I updated my answear.

Comment: Phill, I understand that but LION might be sitting in different positions in different images. Do I need to add a invisible button at LION's position on each image? using IB? Is there a better way to add this image dynamically?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure. Maybe someone else knows a better solution.